# How to deploy a Chain Code with Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, hyperledger-composer

I’m interested into the development of Blockchain Apps using Fabric and Composer.

I’ve got just one question: while Ethereum is a public blockchain so you can deploy your Smart Contract on it and use them freely, can we do the same thing with Fabric? Let me explain: Ethereum has a running Blockchain on which we can work and access, but Fabric has not, right? Should I set up an entire new blockchain network before (setting up all the nodes, giving permissions etc.)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric is different to the blockchain systems you mention in it is private and permissioned. Rather than an open permissionless system that allows unknown identities to participate in the network (requiring protocols like “proof of work” to validate transactions and secure the network), the members of a Hyperledger Fabric network enroll through a trusted Membership Service Provider (MSP). Member organisations would generally set up their own Fabric infrastructure, if they're participating in the blockchain network (context provided earlier). See more on FAQ here -> http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/Fabric-FAQ.html and understand more on key Fabric Concepts here -> http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/key_concepts.html . As for Hyperledger Composer, that is a development framework, with tools etc to accelerate development and abstract things to a business level (ie App development using structure/validated, model driven development as a given). See more here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction (and also see the architectural and key concept links there).

So yes, you will have a running, private blockchain network (including all of the functionality discussed in the docs) with Hyperledger Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

As in Ethereum we can able to create public blockchain and then the user can able to run smart contract on it,  same thing we can do in Hyperledger fabric also.
Hyperledger Fabric has the same functionality as smart contracts called as “chaincode”.
A chaincode is a program that is written to read and update the ledger state. All the business logic handled by chaincode.

For example, if a transaction created then chaincode share and update the ledger throughout the network.

About a Fabric based running blockchain we can work on it and can access it but that's only possible when someone from existing network invites you.

It is quite difficult to say you should setup an entire new blockchain network until I know your use case. Based on your use case you can setup  an entire new blockchain network using fabric which will be private.